# How to read values from xml and set it to bean in java?

Tags: java, android, xml

The xml looks like below mentioned format and the name is "song.xml"

```
<song>
<id>1</id>
<title>sony</title>
</song>
<song>
    <id>4</id>
    <title>shal</title>
</song>
<song>
    <id>5</id>
    <title>eminem</title>
</song>
<song>
    <id>2</id>
    <title>cent</title>
</song>
```

The java bean class looks like below mentioned. Its name is "song.java"

```
 Class song {

    Public String id= null;
    Public String title= null;

   public int getid() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setid(int songNumber) {
        this.id = songNumber;
    }

    public int gettitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setid(String songTitle) {
        this.title = songTitle;
    }
}
```

My question is how can i parse the xml and **set** the value to the java bean?

Comment: Have you considered Smooks? http://www.smooks.org/ This allows you to bind XML to Java Beans.

Comment: Another good post: http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/jaxb-xml-binding-tutorial-marshalling-unmarshalling-java-object-xml.html